# « Vée dicou, gentilastre ! [...] » : le Limousin à Pantagruel (Rabelais) ?

Tags: sens, régionalismes, littérature, lexique, dialectes

> Vée dicou, gentilastre ! Ho, sainct Marsault, adjouda my ! Hau, hau,
>   laissas à quau, au nom de Dious, et ne me touquas grou !
>
> [ Réponse d'un [Limousin](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Limousin) à Pantagruel, ds. le [*Pantagruel*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6520521v/f51.image)
>   (1532), de [Rabelais](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Rabelais) ]

---

C'est évidemment un dialecte fort différent de ce que l'écolier lui avait servi précédemment (« *Nous transfretons la Sequane au dilucule et crepuscule ; nous deambulons par les compites et quadrivies de l'urbe ; nous despumons la verbocination latiale* [...] », *ibid.*). C'est que Rabelais se moque à l'évidence d'un parler latinisant, qui n'est pas naturel et qui sonne faux. Mais la réponse finale de l'écolier dans son œuvre est en [limousin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limousin_(dialecte)) (un dialecte de l'occitan, ayant parfois fait l'objet d'un certain niveau de déconsidération en littérature), et même si je peux me douter vaguement de ce qu'on peut bien vouloir dire, vue la syntaxe, j'aimerais comprendre plus précisément la réponse, en particulier le sens de *vée dicou/adjouda my/à quau/touquas grou* et savoir si *ho/hau hau* sont des interjections et s'il y a des parallèles au lexique avec le français, puisqu'on parle de langues romanes. C'est la question !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voilà comment je traduirais ce dialecte, d'abord en occitan "classique", puis en français:

> *Vée dicou, gentilastre !*
>
> *Véi dich, gentilòme !*
>
> Regarde dit, gentihomme !
>
> ---
>
> *Ho, sainct Marsault, adjouda my !*
>
> *Òu, Sant Marçau, ajuda-me !*
>
> Oh ! Saint Martial, aide-moi !
>
> ---
>
> *Hau, hau, laissas à quau, au nom de Dious, et ne me touquas grou !*
>
> *Òu, òu, daissas aquò, al nom de Dieu, e non me tocas grèu !*
>
> Oh ! Oh ! Laisse ça, au nom de Dieu, et ne me touche pas gravement !

---

Après comparaison des traductions existantes, il n'y a pas de consensus sur *Vée dicou* qui est traduit « Eh, je dis » (*È, disi*) ou « Par pitié » (?), *Laissas a quau* est traduit « laisse-moi » (?), *grèu* est parfois traduit « guère » (*gaire*) ou simplement ignoré.

Comment: Juste pour information, tu as des connaissances personnelles d'occitan ou tu t'appuies sur un support particulier?

Comment: Les deux, je me suis bien sûr aidé d'un dictionnaire et d'une grammaire. http://www.panoccitan.org/diccionari.aspx?diccion=al&lenga=oc

Comment: D'accord, super traduction en tout cas ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Dans l'édition de la Pléiade (texte établi et annoté par Jacques Boulenger, édition revue et commentée par Lucien Scheler, p193), il est donné la traduction suivante dans les commentaires :

> Eh! je dis, gentilhomme! Oh! saint Martial secours-moi! Han han, laisse-moi, au nom de Dieu, et ne me touche guère!

Comment: Merci ! Cette riche édition apporte un éclairage intéressant et c'est malheureusement uniquement la deuxième fois qu'on s'en sert depuis la création du site pour appuyer une réponse. J'ai sélectionné la réponse avec le plus d'analyse, mais j'estime que le texte de la Pléiade fait autorité.